Restriction functor in group cohomology action on map of free modules
Let $G$ be a group and $H\le G$ a subgroup of finite index $|G:H|=n<\infty$.
I understand that because the right translation action of $H$ on $G$ is free, the integral group ring $\mathbb{Z}G$ is a free right $\mathbb{Z}H$-module and as a basis we can take any set $E$ of representatives for the left cosets $gH$.
Said otherwise, there is an isomorphism $$\mathrm{res}_{H}^{G}(\mathbb{Z}G)\cong \bigoplus_{g\in E} (g\cdot \mathbb{Z}H)\cong(\mathbb{Z}H)^{n},$$
where $\mathrm{res}_{H}^{G}(-):\mathrm{Mod-}\mathbb{Z}G \to \mathrm{Mod-}\mathbb{Z}H$ is the restriction functor induced by the inclusion $H\hookrightarrow G$.
I am having trouble understanding the action of this functor on a map of free $\mathbb{Z}G$-modules.
That is to say, given a map of finite rank free $\mathbb{Z}G$-modules $d:(\mathbb{Z}G)^{n}\to (\mathbb{Z}G)^{m}$, how can can we understand the restricted map $$\mathrm{res}_{H}^{G}(d):\mathrm{res}_{H}^{G}((\mathbb{Z}G)^{n})\to \mathrm{res}_{H}^{G}((\mathbb{Z}G)^{m})$$
In particular, if I explicitly know the entries of $d$ for a particular basis of $\mathbb{Z}G$ and also have an explicit set $E$ of representatives for the left cosets $gH$, then can I write the map $\mathrm{res}_{H}^{G}(d)$ down as a (possibly very large) matrix with entries in the ring $\mathbb{Z}H$?
